Prove that a parametrized surface is a hyperboloid of one sheet
A surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is bilinearly parametrized by $s,t$
$$\tag1\label1
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x=a_0+a_1 s+a_2 t+a_3 s t \\
y=b_0+b_1 s+b_2 t+b_3 s t \\
z=c_0+c_1 s+c_2 t+c_3 s t
\end{array}\right.
$$
Suppose $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3,c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3$ are real constants satisfying the inequality
$$\tag{i}\det\left(\begin{array}{lll}a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{array}\right) \neq 0$$
The implicit equation for (1) is given by the
determinant
$$\tag2\det\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
a_0-x & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & 0 & 0 \\
b_0-y & b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & 0 & 0 \\
c_0-z & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a_0-x & 0 & a_2 & a_1 & a_3 \\
0 & b_0-y & 0 & b_2 & b_1 & b_3 \\
0 & c_0-z & 0 & c_2 & c_1 & c_3
\end{array}\right)
$$
The easier direction is to prove that the determinant (2) is zero if $x, y, z$ are given by (1). Multiply the equations in (1) by $1, s$ respectively to get a system of 6 equations.
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x=a_0+a_1 s+a_2 t+a_3 s t \\
y=b_0+b_1 s+b_2 t+b_3 s t \\
z=c_0+c_1 s+c_2 t+c_3 s t \\
xs=a_0s+a_1 s^2+a_2st+a_3 s^2t \\
ys=b_0s+b_1 s^2+b_2st+b_3 s^2t \\
zs=c_0s+c_1 s^2+c_2st+c_3 s^2t \\
\end{array}\right.
$$
Consider this set of equations as a system of equations with $1, s, t, s t, s^2, s^2 t$ as variables, then the determinant of the coefficient matrix of this linear system is zero.
The other direction is, assuming that the determinant (2) is zero, to prove that there exist $s, t$ such that (1) holds.
Let $\boldsymbol{A}$ be the matrix in (2), then there exists a non-zero vector $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=\left(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_6\right)^T$ such that $\boldsymbol{A} \cdot \boldsymbol{\alpha}=0$. Using inequality (i) one can prove that $\alpha_1 \neq 0$.
Comparing rows 1,2,3 with rows 4,5,6 in $\boldsymbol{A} \cdot \boldsymbol{\alpha}=0$ we have $\alpha_1:\alpha_2:\alpha_3:\alpha_4=\alpha_2:\alpha_5:\alpha_4:\alpha_6$.
Multiply $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ by $1 / \alpha_1$, still denote it as $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$, then $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=(1, s, t, \alpha_4, \alpha_5, \alpha_6)$. From $\alpha_1:\alpha_3=\alpha_2:\alpha_4$ we get $\alpha_4=s t$. Thus (1) is equivalent to $(2)=0$.

We see that (2) is a polynomial of total degree 2 in $x, y$ and $z$.
So the surface is a quadric in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
By taking $t$ constant in (1), the surface contains a straight line.
Question
Is the surface (1) a hyperboloid of one sheet?

The homogenization of (2) is $\det\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 a_0 w-x & a_1 w & a_2 & a_3 & 0 & 0 \\
 b_0 w-y & b_1 w & b_2 & b_3 & 0 & 0 \\
 c_0 w-z & c_1 w & c_2 & c_3 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & a_0 w-x & 0 & a_2 & a_1 & a_3 \\
 0 & b_0 w-y & 0 & b_2 & b_1 & b_3 \\
 0 & c_0 w-z & 0 & c_2 & c_1 & c_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$
Substitute $w=0$, $\det\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 -x & 0 & a_2 & a_3 & 0 & 0 \\
 -y & 0 & b_2 & b_3 & 0 & 0 \\
 -z & 0 & c_2 & c_3 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -x & 0 & a_2 & a_1 & a_3 \\
 0 & -y & 0 & b_2 & b_1 & b_3 \\
 0 & -z & 0 & c_2 & c_1 & c_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$
By Laplace expansion, this equals
$\det\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -x & a_1 & a_3 \\
 -y & b_1 & b_3 \\
 -z & c_1 & c_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)  \det\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -x & a_2 & a_3 \\
 -y & b_2 & b_3 \\
 -z & c_2 & c_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)=0$
So the plane at infinity cuts the surface in two lines.
Does the inequality (i) imply that the surface is not a cylinder?

There are plenty of lines,  but there are plenty of non-cylindrical ruled surfaces. The simplest choice of constants results in the saddle surface $z=xy$.

@TedShifrin Thanks. I was wrong. I edited the statement.
